# Aligning graphic based bullet points with css

Tags: css

I have made a list of bullet points with icons, but i cant get the text to align nicely.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
    <li class="moutlook">List</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 110%;
    margin: 0px 0 15px 45px;
    padding-top:0px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    line-height: 0;
}
.moutlook {
    list-style-image: url(../images/icon.png);
    padding-top: 10px
}
```

I have tried all sort as you can see, at the moment it's like this:

```
-------
-     -
-     -
------- List
```

When it should be like this:

```
-------
-     - List (well in the middle)
-     -
-------
```

I plan to use a different icon on each, what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `background-image` instead of `list-style-image`. First, you'll have to add these declarations for cross-browser compatibility.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;  
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;  
}
```

Then replace your `.moutlook` declarations with these:

```
.moutlook {
    background-image: url(../images/icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: (width of your image + 7) px;
    line-height: (height of your image) px;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGXeG/) for a live example.

Comment: But that messes up the line height of my content.

Comment: @Geoist This answers the OP's question. You should ask a new question since you seem to have different requirements.

Comment: Thanks, but I've solved my issue.  I just wanted to point out an issue with your solution for future consideration.

Comment: @Geoist There's no issue as far as the OP is concerned. Line height issues are out of the question's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing:

```
.moutlook {
    list-style-image: url(../images/icon.png);
    padding-top: 10px
}
```

To:

```
.moutlook {
    list-style-image: url(../images/icon.png);
    padding-top: 5px
    padding-bottom: 5px
}
```

Comment: I must admit I never use list-style-image, and always use melhosseiny's solution. That should work for you.